# Symfony YML + Don't add ' to string with multiple words

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

I'm looking for strings in a file and save them to a yml file. 
When the string is one word like `Map` it shows `Map` in the yml file. But if the string is `Permit Total` I get `'Permit Total'`.

How can I fix this? (That it just prints Permit Total)

I'm using the `symfony\yaml` library.

Comment: what do you want to get? provide an example please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In YAML, single and double quotes are used to denote a String and aren't actually part of the String value. In other words, `Map` and `'Map'` are equivalent.

When you parse the YAML file to retrieve a String with double or single quotes around it, the quotes won't be included.

Take a look:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Syntax